# Retrieving EXIF info and video informations from pictures/movies

Tags: java, image, exif, movie, codec

is there a Java framework that will do the dirty work explained in title for me?

Mainly I just need to retrieve images properties stored inside JPEGs:

- size
- EXIF
- geolocations
- shot properties

and to retrieve movie files informations like:

- codec name
- duration
- resolution
- and so on

I don't need to be able to show the picture or play the movie, just to get the properties without having to write my own file header parsers..

while for images I mainly need JPEG support for movies it would be nice to be able to open as many formats as possible (avi, mkv, mp4, mpeg, mov, etc)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/ to extract EXIF from JPEG.

Comment: Nice library, but with my Nikon D90, `metadata-extractor-2.5.0-RC2` return no ISO data from EXIF :(